# How to take four input values from a single ListView item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which of it's items contains four different input values. My task is when I click any of the item it has to take the input values and store it in four different variables.

The list view items were in following format:

> !+11.3326,+077.7193,08:41!+11.3326,+077.7194,08:41#

Comment: i don't have enough reputation score. so i can't post the screenshot of my app.

Comment: Post at least code..

Comment: if it is a one string then you can separate string any parts and store in different variables otherwise post your code what you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by blind guess, suppose you have `ListView listView` and `ArrayList<String> items` which represent your data, then, you go like this :

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String[] values = items.get(position).split("+") // your separator here, i gues it is "+";
                //Do with your values whatever you want
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm using ArrayAdapter

Comment: you're putting list of values to it, that list is your data, and i'm guessing its ArrayList of String or some type

Comment: and you could just simply copy paste your code here...

Comment: `final ListView lViewSMS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS);
     if (fetchInbox() != null) {
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fetchInbox());
            lViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        lViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click ListItem Number"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });`

Comment: `public ArrayList fetchInbox(){
     ArrayList sms=new ArrayList();
     Uri uriSms=Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
     Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id","address","date","body"},null,null,null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     while (cursor.moveToNext()){
      String address=cursor.getString(1);
      String body=cursor.getString(3);
         System.out.println("======&gt;Mobile Number=&gt;"+address);
            System.out.println("=====&gt;SMS Text=&gt;"+body);
            sms.add("Ph.No:"+address+"\n SMS:"+body);
        }
        return sms;
    }`

Comment: You should make this local variable __ArrayList sms__ as field in your class to have reference for it, and in onItemClick you can just take it from there like : __Uri uri =  sms.get(position)__;  Then you can go : __String[] values = uri.toString().split(",")//or other separator for your parts__. And you have array with 4 your parts, which you can parse to needed variables now, that's all